# How can I de-Normalize data that is normalized with keras.utils.normalize()?

Tags: python, keras, normalization

I want to de-normalize data after trainig.
I'using for the normalization:
`X_train=keras.utils.normalize(X_train0,axis=1)`
How can I de-normalize data?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The [normalize](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/normalize) function either takes the square (L2 Norm) or absolute value (L1 Norm). To get back the original, you might get the square root or absolute value, but you cannot know the sign (positive or negative). You can just keep a copy of the unnormalized data somewhere.